# Oracle HTTP Server htdocs

Tags: oracle, apache, mod-plsql

The trouble is, while PL/SQL procedures do generate HTML, I cannot make image folder work. That is, when I try to insert an IMG tag, it shows that it can't find that file in `/xxx/img folder`.

I tried to redefine DocumentRoot in *httpd.conf* - it works only on that folder itself, not recursively.
I tried to change DOCUMENT_ROOT in *dads.conf* - it doesn't work at all.

So the question is, how can I make images deep inside that root folder show up?

Comment: Oracle HTTP Server is basicaly improved Apache server, your images has nothing to do with pl/sql container. So just configure it as plain apache server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At last I have found an answer and a reason of this behavior.

The reason is Oracle's hand-made handler, `pls_handler`, used for any DADs, made up as Apache Locations.

Trying to create folders for storing images like `$ORACLE_HOME/htdocs/myapp/img`, I interfered with that directive:

```
<Location /myapp>
    SetHandler pls_handler
    # lots of stuff
</Location>
```

And thus, anything under `$ORACLE_HOME/htdocs/myapp` folder was processed as PL/SQL procedures.

Answer (score 1):

This is a plain Apache configuration issue. You simply must define an alias in your Apache configuration file.

Assume that your image resources are in a directory `/middleware/project/img`. Then just add the following line to your httpd.conf or (that's where I configure it) dads.conf:

`Alias /i/ "/middleware/project/img/"`

If you now have a file `alert.png` in your `/middleware/project/img` directory you can access it with an `/i/alert.png` url.

Comment: Thanks, worth trying.

Comment: Not sure I get you. Did my feedback (not) solve your problem?

Comment: Well, I was taken to another project for a while, so once I get the time to put my hands on this again, I'll try. But thanks in advance for your feedback!